# C++ MapViewOfFile fails

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to memory-map a file on Windows using VS2010. 
I am doing this in a DLL.
The first instance of the DLL maps the file just fine.
The second instance within the same process causes

```
*ppvData = ::MapViewOfFile( *phMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0 );
```

to fail with the error "Not enough memory available for this command".
I am not sure why this happens.

If I map 2 different files instead of twice the same file, all works fine, so I don't trust the "Not enough memory" error message.

Thank you.

```
hr = MapFile(sPath, &m_hVoiceData, &m_pVoiceData,wsErr );

HRESULT CTTSEngObj::MapFile( wstring uPath,  // Value that contains file path
                            HANDLE * phMapping,          // Pointer to file mapping handle
                            void ** ppvData,             // Pointer to the data
                            wstring &uError)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CSpDynamicString dstrFilePath(uPath.c_str());

    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        bool fWorked = false;
        *phMapping = NULL;
        *ppvData = NULL;
        HANDLE hFile;
#ifdef _WIN32_WCE
        hFile = CreateFileForMapping( dstrFilePath, GENERIC_READ,
                                      FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
#else
        hFile = CreateFile(CW2T(dstrFilePath), GENERIC_READ,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
#endif
        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            *phMapping = ::CreateFileMapping( hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL );
            if (*phMapping)
            {
                *ppvData = ::MapViewOfFile( *phMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0 );
                if (*ppvData)
                {
                    fWorked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    uError=GetLastErrorStdStrW();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                uError=L"mapfile: fm failed";
            }
            ::CloseHandle( hFile );
        }
        else
        {
            uError=L"mapfile: invalidhandle";
        }
        if (!fWorked)
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
            if (*phMapping)
            {
                ::CloseHandle(*phMapping);
                *phMapping = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        uError=L"mapfile: dynstr";
    }
    return hr;
} /* CTTSEngObj::MapFile */
```

And this is how it is declared:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTTSEngObj : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CTTSEngObj, &CLSID_SampleTTSEngine>,
    public ISpTTSEngine,
    public ISpObjectWithToken
{

  private:
    CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> m_cpToken;
    HANDLE                  m_hVoiceData;
    void*                   m_pVoiceData;
```

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761.aspx)? Just like pretty much every other Win32 call, "If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx)."

Comment: You should save the error code as soon as a function fails, as there's a chance other API calls (like your call to `CloseHandle`) may modify the value.

Comment: `*phMapping =` and the like look suspicious to me. AFAICT they'll try to write to address 0. Declaring them w/o a type identifier is a bad idea too: the default type is `int` while HANDLE is typically PVOID - the address arithmetic is different.

Comment: It makes no sense to "not trust" Windows, it doesn't just generate an error because it is having a bad day.  The simple explanation is the one that Windows tells you about, the file is too large to fit an available hole in the virtual memory address space.  That's why MapViewOfFile() has the dwNumberOfBytesToMap argument.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It is sample code from the PSDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request to map the entire file into memory. How big is it? There may very well not be a large enough *contiguous* range of unallocated process's address space.

Comment: The thing is that if I do the same from a different process, it works.

Comment: "A different process" has different virtual address space.

Comment: The file is 200 mb in size.

Comment: Given the possible address space fragmentation and other possible limitations, it's large enough for that. You may try to map a part of the file to check this.

Comment: But... should it then also not work if I use 2 different processes?

Comment: All in all, why do you need 2 identical mappings of the same file in the same process? Due to the mapping's workings, their contents will always be the same!

Comment: I have no control over it. I do the mapping at the DLL startup. If the DLL is instanciated, the mapping is done automatically because else the DLL does not have a mapped file to work with.

Comment: For better readability I have put the declaration in my post.

Comment: Another process has its own virtual address space. Allocating address space in one process doesn't affect others. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory on this. The DLL is loaded only once for each process so you can create mapping in its global startup code.

Comment: You mean that I should create a named file mapping and let the DLL try to use it? And if it isn't found, I have to create this file mapping?

Comment: No, I mean create it only once, in `DllMain()` or on demand, and store the reference in a location accessible from the entire DLL so it's reused. I'm not sure if multiple copies of the same named mapping in the same process will share address space (though they probably will).

Comment: In any case, we drifted off topic. The question was why it fails. Did you check if lesser mappings work as I suggested?

Comment: I am just compiling my app... I will test that as soon as I am able to work again.

Comment: Well, with a smaller file it works. I guess that is equal to mapping only a part of the file (this way it was quicker for me). Although not my solution yet, you answered my problem. Thank you.