# How to find a specific byte sequence between two file offsets in a binary file using Python?

Tags: python, binary, python-3.4

> How to find a specific byte sequence between two file offsets in a binary file using Python?

I want to open a binary file to search for a specific byte sequence `0x66,0x66,...,0x66` between two file offsets `start` and `end`.

My idea is to open the file using `rb` and then set the file position to `start` using `fseek()`. Then for each position in the file, I read 16 bytes and compare them to the sequence above (16 bytes in length).

However, there must be an easier way to do this?

Comment: How large is the file? If it's not small enough to read the whole thing, you may be able to use a [memory-mapped file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html).

Comment: Lets say ~100MB.

Comment: That should be ok to read the whole thing, but I think `mmap` will be faster.

Comment: [`mmap` is very versatile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643919/python-string-processing-optimization)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say it was a large file, so let's assume it fits easily into memory.  fseek to the start position, then read end-start bytes. You'll have a bytestring, then you can use .index to find your sequence:

```
with open("the_file.bin", "rb") as f:
    f.fseek(start)
    data = f.read(end-start)
where = data.index(b"\x66"*16)
```

Comment: Does this give me ALL indicies?

Comment: @Shuzheng No, it just gives you the first one. You'll need to loop to find the other indices. You may wish to use `.find` instead of `.index`, otherwise you'll need a `try:... except` block to catch the `ValueError` raised by `.index` when your pattern can't be found.